# assigning x to point to where y is pointing to does that cause any memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

i am assigning x to point to where y is pointing to does that cause any memory leaks? If yes what is the correct way to do it?

```
int *x, *y
x = new int;
y = new int;
*x = 3;
*y = 4;
x  = y;
delete x;
```

Comment: Yes. The other answer varies, but most will say to use smart pointers.

Comment: Yep. As soon as you repoint `x` it's previous allocation has been lost.  You'll need a `delete x;` before assigning.

Comment: @user4581301 Prefer not to answer in comments, and instead in the answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, *draw pictures*!

We start here:

```
int *x, *y;

+---------+
|    x    |-----> ???
+---------+

+---------+
|    y    |-----> ???
+---------+
```

We have two uninitialized pointers, and that means that they're pointing basically "wherever."

Next, we say

```
x = new int;
y = new int;

+---------+       +----------+
|    x    |-----> | ???????? |
+---------+       +----------+

+---------+       +----------+
|    y    |-----> | ???????? |
+---------+       +----------+
```

The pointers `x` and `y` now point to integers, but since those integers haven't been initialized their values are essentially "whatever."

Carrying on:

```
*x = 3;
*y = 4;

+---------+       +---------+
|    x    |-----> |    3    |
+---------+       +---------+

+---------+       +---------+
|    y    |-----> |    4    |
+---------+       +---------+
```

Two nicely-behaved pointers, pointing at nicely-behaved integers. Ahh, how nice!

But then, alas, tragedy strikes:

```
x = y;

+---------+       +---------+
|    x    |---+   |    3    |
+---------+   |   +---------+
              |
+---------+   +-> +---------+
|    y    |-----> |    4    |
+---------+       +---------+
```

Oh no! We've left the integer 3 lost, adrift in the void, with no one to love it. It's a memory leak! How sad.

When we round things off, we say

```
delete x;

+---------+       +---------+
|    x    |---+   |    3    |
+---------+   |   +---------+
              |
+---------+   +->  
|    y    |----->   deallocated
+---------+           memory!
```

It's not inherently a problem that `x` and `y` now point to deallocated memory. It's just a consequence of what happened.

So yes, you do have a memory leak. What can you do about it? Well, that really depends on what you're trying to do. @Ray Hamel's idea is to use smart pointers to automagically clean up the memory when `x` is reassigned. And that's not a bad idea. But given that this code looks like it's a small example designed to get you thinking about pointers, you could also try something like deallocating the memory pointed at by `x` before reassigning it. It's hard to say what the "right thing" is here because this example doesn't actually accomplish anything "deep," if that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this would be a memory leak. You can avoid the memory leak by `delete`-ing `x` before assigning `y` to `x`. Then, since `x` and `y` are pointing to the same object, you must `delete` exactly one (not both!) of `x` and `y`.

In general you should prefer the [RAII pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to calling `new` and `delete` directly. The standard library provides smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and container classes like `std::vector` which follow this useful pattern.

Answer (score 2):

A memory leak occurs when you lose track of an allocation. The only way to release memory is to retain the pointer somewhere. So long as you move that pointer you're able to release it later, but stomping it like this causes the value to be lost.

It's the `x = y` line that's the issue. If you did `delete x` first, you're good.

In other words this is fine:

```cpp
delete x;
x = y; 
delete x;
```

But this is not:

```cpp
x = y; // Original x pointer is now lost, can't release it
```

Nor is this:

```cpp
delete x;
x = y; 
delete x;
delete y; // Pointer has already been deleted on the previous line
```

Every `new` should be paired with a `delete`. If you have more of one than the other you've got an issue.

In other words, it's the *specific pointer value* that matters, not the variable. The variable is just a way for humans to describe values the compiler is working with.